# How to save as uint16 in file without using all the bytes?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, yuv

This is a simple example of what I want to do:

```
num = 4
fid = fopen('test.yuv','w+');
fwrite(fid,num,'uint16');
fclose(fid);
```

I need to save `4` in `test.yuv` but it keeps saving an array of `4 0` because of `uint16`. Is there a way to save only `4` in the file?

- It has to be saved in `.yuv` with `uint16` , and can be done in another language if necessary.

Comment: "but it keeps saving an array of  `4 0`" How exactly are you determining this? `fid = fopen('test.yuv','r'); test = fread(fid, 'uint16'); fclose(fid)` returns `4`, as expected.

Comment: Oh thank you, I was using another way to read it. But do you if inside the file is storing only 4? I won't use this file in matlab, so I need to make sure that 0 is not being storaged.

Comment: If you look at the file in a hex editor, you’ll see two bytes, one 4 and one 0. Together these form a single 16-bit number. If you need there to be a 4 as uint16, then you need that 0 there, otherwise it will only be uint8.